# How can I make the programs I had open on shutdown open on turn on?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am reluctant to turn off my computer now because I have a specific set of windows 
(not web tabs) open that I would rather not close. Instead I keep hibernating. I would like 
to be able to turn of my Windows 7 computer and have all the work I had open formerly open 
again. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you always open the same programs after starting your computer, such as a web browser or an e‑mail program, you might find it convenient to have them start automatically when you start Windows. Programs or shortcuts placed in the Startup folder will run whenever Windows starts.

Click the Start button, click All Programs, right-click the Startup folder, and then click Open.
Open the location that contains the item you want to create a shortcut to.

Right-click the item, and then click Create Shortcut. The new shortcut appears in the same location as the original item.

Drag the shortcut into the Startup folder.

The next time you start Windows, the program will run automatically.

Note

You can also make an individual file, such as a word-processing document, open automatically by dragging a shortcut of the file into the Startup folder.

source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 0):

What you have open is in RAM. When you "Shut Down" the computer, RAM is cleared. So as your question stands, I would say No.

Answer (score 0):

Vinicius Santana's answer is as good as you'll get.

However, even using his advice, you might find that your applications might not start with the same window positions and sizes you had when you shut down (depends on the applications of course).

Also whenever you change your mind about what *specific* set of applications and documents you want open on start up, you'll have to re-jig things in the Startup folder. That'll get tedious pretty quickly.

Hibernation was designed (in part) to solve the exact problem you're trying to solve. If hibernation is working well on your system, why not continue to use it?